# Find data type of measures in Cube using MDX queries

Tags: c#, ssas, mdx, adomd.net

I am working SSAS MDX queries. Now I need to identify the data type of each columns from the MDX queries. I have already tried as below.

```
WITH MEMBER PageSize AS 1  Member [Measures].[My Type] as TypeName([Measures].[Budget Delivered COGS])
```

[image]

But it returns double for the currency field. First of all does Cubes have the data type as currency, percentage?

If not, is there is any way to find out whether the column is currency or percentage or double or integer?

I have seen this post [Find the data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951314/retrieving-data-type-of-measures-from-an-mdx-query-cellset-in-c-sharp). But that is not feasible with the currency and percentage.

Here I am pasting my entire query.

```
 WITH MEMBER PageSize AS
  1
MEMBER [Measures].[My Type] AS
  TypeName ( [Measures].[Budget Delivered COGS] )
MEMBER [PageNumber] AS
  1
MEMBER [Measures].[Orderby Measure] AS
  [Measures].[Budget Delivered COGS]
MEMBER [Orderby] AS
  "BASC"
SET ROWAXISWOF AS
  NonEmpty (
    ( [Time Periods].[Fiscal Year].[Fiscal Year].Members, [Time Periods].[Fiscal Quarter].[Fiscal Quarter].Members, [Time Periods].[Fiscal Month].[Fiscal Month].Members, [Time Periods].[Fiscal Week].[Fiscal Week].Members ),
    {
      { [Measures].[Budget Delivered COGS] },
      { [Measures].[Break Even Delivered] }
    }
  )
SET ROWAXISWF AS
  Filter ( ROWAXISWOF, [Measures].[Budget Delivered COGS] )
SET ROWAXIS AS
  IIf ( 'Filter' = "NotFilter", ROWAXISWF, ROWAXISWOF )
MEMBER [Measures].[MaxRowCount] AS
  ROWAXIS .Count
SET ROWAXIS_Count AS
  IIf (
    'Paging' = "Paging",
    (
    CASE
    WHEN [Orderby] = 'BASC'
    THEN Tail (
      TopCount ( ROWAXIS, PageSize * PageNumber, [Measures].[Orderby Measure] ),
      PageSize
    )
    ELSE Tail (
      BottomCount ( ROWAXIS, PageSize * PageNumber, [Measures].[Orderby Measure] ),
      PageSize
    ) END ),
    ROWAXISWOF
  )
SELECT ( IIf (
  'Paging' = "Paging",
  (
  { [Measures].[Budget Delivered COGS], [Measures].[Break Even Delivered], [Measures].[MaxRowCount], [Measures].[My Type] } ),
  { [Measures].[Budget Delivered COGS], [Measures].[Break Even Delivered], [Measures].[My Type] }
) ) ON COLUMNS,
ROWAXIS_Count ON ROWS
FROM (
  SELECT (
  { [Time Periods].[Fiscal Year].&[2011], [Time Periods].[Fiscal Year].&[2012], [Time Periods].[Fiscal Year].&[2013], [Time Periods].[Fiscal Year].&[2014], [Time Periods].[Fiscal Year].&[2015] } ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Homestore Sales]
)
```

If we get the data in the query, I will loop through the column and find out in C#. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say that the `$` is purely related to the `format_string` associated with the budget delivered measure - as opposed to a specific type. Are you not able to assume that all data extracted from cube is nvarchar and then convert further later in your process?

Comment: @whytheq Thank you so much for your reply. Do you mean, looping through the each values and if any value in the cell contain $ in it, then consider the measure is a currency?

Comment: @sibeeth - I don't think the `$` will be present when you get the data via ADOMD as it is just formatting applied by `ssas` (...but I'm just guessing really and have starred your question as I'm interested in any answers)

Comment: @whytheq Thank you so much for that. And I checked if we get the result as CellSet and while looping through the cellset if we take FormattedValue, the values are containing $ and also %.

Comment: @sibeeth - I think you can assume all values that you get from the cellset are `nvarchar` - then try converting them to other formats. Small numbers are not easy to work with from SSAS because they seem to come out as scientific notation (with an `E` in them and are therefore challenging to convert - we CAST them as FLOAT first)

Comment: @whytheq Thanks for your reply. When you return from cell set, if you use caption instead of using Name, you will get the actual values (With out scientific notation E).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99367/discussion-between-sibeesh-venu-and-whytheq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about physical measures, then you can look in SSDT-BI in your SSAS project to see the measure type. Or you can export it in bulk with the following SSAS sproc you can install [here](https://asstoredprocedures.codeplex.com/):

```
CALL ASSP.discoverXmlMetaData("\Database\Cubes\Cube\MeasureGroups\MeasureGroup|Name\Measures\Measure");
```

Calculated measures are trickier. It is possible for CalculatedMeasure1 to be type Double in one cell and String in another cell because of IIF statements and scope statements in the calculation. You could run a query and get back a CellSet then look a the type of each individual cell and I think it should tell you the type. But I'm not sure what good that would do you given types can vary from cell to cell even among the same calculated measure.

Maybe you want to retrieve the FORMAT_STRING property for the calculated measure? That might indicate what to expect. In the resulting CellSet, you will be able to retrieve the FORMAT_STRING property from each cell.

```
select {[Measures].[Budget Delivered COGS], [Measures].[Break Even Delivered]} on 0
FROM [Homestore Sales]
PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING
```

A final way to do this, if you want to assume each measure will have the same format string for all cells in the cube, is to query the [MDSCHEMA_MEASURES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms126250.aspx) DMV. It has a DEFAULT_FORMAT_STRING column. You can call it with a SQL query against SSAS like:

```
select * from $system.mdschema_measures
```

Or you can call it through ADOMD.NET with code such as:

```
AdomdRestrictionCollection restrictions = new AdomdRestrictionCollection();
restrictions.Add(new AdomdRestriction("CATALOG_NAME", cube.ParentConnection.Database));
restrictions.Add(new AdomdRestriction("CUBE_NAME", cube.Name));
System.Data.DataTable tblExactMatchMembers = conn.GetSchemaDataSet("MDSCHEMA_MEASURES", restrictions).Tables[0];
```

If that doesn't answer your question you might provide a little more background what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi GregGalloway, thank you so much for your answer. This PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING will only return the basic types like double or string. But my requirement is bit different. I need to know which one is currency or percentage types too. What I do now is, just looping through each cells and checks whether if it contains $ in it, it is currency and same for % too. Since I am looping through every cells, it is causing some performance issues.

Comment: Are you trying to build a generic client tool that works for any cube? Or are you just trying to consume your particular cube? Does your cube have scope statements that would mean on measure is formatted differently per cell?

Comment: @SibeeshVenu, I edited my answer to mention MDSCHEMA_MEASURES

Comment: Yes you are right. I am trying to build a tool that works in all cube. I will try MDSCHEMA_MEASURES and let you know. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: #,##0.00;-#,##0.00
#,##0.00;-#,##0.00
#,##0.00;-#,##0.00
#,##0.00;-#,##0.00
Currency
Currency
Currency
Currency
$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)
$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)
$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)
$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00)
#,##0.00;-#,##0.00
#,##0.00;-#,##0.00
#,##0.00;-#,##0.00
Percent
Percent
Currency When I run the query I get the type as above. But can you please say me what is that # means? Thanks in advance

Comment: Formatting 99 with the format string #,##0 would just be 99. But formatting 9999 would be 9,999. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146084.aspx